# jQuery animate height on element with min-height property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element with a min-height of 300px set in CSS:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="summary"></div>
<div id="collapse"></div>
/* CSS */
#summary { min-height: 300px }
```

When I click on the `#collapse` element, I would like the `#summary` element to collapse smoothly to a height of 100px.

```
$("#collapse").click(function() {
   $("#summary").animate({ height: 100}, 1000);
});
```

However, nothing is happening, and I think that is because of the min-height property.

I [have read this discussion on the jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/animations-should-temporarily-override-min-height-and-min-width), but I still can't figure out how to make the `#summary` div animate smoothly - setting the min-height to auto as they suggest makes the div vanish and then reappear! Can anyone help?

UPDATE: I've made [a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/8jn7v/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `height` in css in instead of `min-height` as you decrease the height to 100 and min-height is 300 on `click` event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/8qkxH/)**

Change

```
#summary { min-height: 300px }
```

To

```
#summary { height: 300px; }
```

*If you need to use min-width then you need to change min-width in animate instead of height.*

Comment: Thank you, that's the best solution for me, so I have accepted it.

Comment: although `min-height` can also be animated.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to do something like

```
$("#collapse").click(function() {
   var summary = $("#summary"),
       height  = summary.height();

   summary
     .css({ height: height + 'px', minHeight: 0 }) 
     .animate({ height: 100}, 1000);
});
```

The idea is to reset the `min-height` and set the css `height` property to the computed height of the element itself just before the animation.

Answer (score 1):

try this out in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/8jn7v/5/**

change this:

```
height: 50
```

to this:

```
$('#summary').animate({ 
  'min-height': 50+'px' // <--see the quotes at min-height and add pixels to it
}, 1000);
```

`min-height` lets you not to decrease the height lesser than the `min-height`

your element is limited to `300px` because of the `min-height` so you have to animate the `min-height` instead of `height`